# Configuring the sonarqube gitlab plugin, preview mode

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gitlab

I am trying to configure the [Gilab Sonar Plugin](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/issues/57), so we can get sonar review comments in merge requests.

We have configured our gradle project,  [as per documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle) and through gitlab-ci.yml, we call sonarqube task:

```
# Run sonar feature analysis
sonar_feature:
 stage: sonar
 only:
   - /^BE-*/
 tags:
   - gitlab-runner-docker
 script:
  - ./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
  -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=${CI_PROJECT_PATH}
  -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=${CI_COMMIT_SHA} 
  -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} -Dsonar.verbose=true
```

The 'sonarqube' task completes in gradle, but an 'external' job remains in running status, without completing . In Sonarqube itself, I don't see a new background task, so it seems analysis is not really occurring and it's a hanging/waiting mode.

Notes: 
1. We don't see logging on the sonar_feature job, eventhough sonar.verbose=true.

What could be the issue?

[image: Screenshot Gitlab]

Comment: I have similar problem. @Christophe have you mange to fix it?

Comment: Didn't manage to fix this unfortunately, might have another go at it soon though...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I had not configured `sonar.gitlab.user_token`.

Generate a User Token in GITLAB and add it to your sonar properties